# Distributing Objects in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to figure out how to distribute some square objects evenly all the way around a path. It's a rounded rectangle.

I've tried using object > blend but there's only an option to align the objects to the center of the path. Is there another tool that can be used to accomplish this?

[image: 1image1]
[image: image2]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a scatter brush.

- Draw a single of your shapes
- Drag it to the brushes panel and select "Scatter Brush"
- Make sure everything is set to "Fixed" and add some spacing. Adjust the scatter to change the alignment relative to the path; −50% will align the artwork inside the path, 50% will align the artwork to the outside... then hit OK.

[image]

- Use your new scatter brush on your rounded rectangle...

[image]

The spacing is based on a percentage of the artwork's size, not the path itself, so is unlikely to fit perfectly straight away; you can edit the brush (double click the brush in the brushes panel) after applying it to the rectangle and adjust the spacing on the fly though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with blends if you have the blend follow your path’s "spine."

To adjust the shape of the spine, drag the anchor points and path segments on the spine with the *Direct Selection* tool.

To replace the spine with a different path, draw an object to use as the new spine.

Select the spine object and the blended object, and choose *Object → Blend → Replace Spine.*

[Related Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=replace+spine+illustrator+blend)